# Spring mongo read conversion fails for beans inside a map

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a very strange situation where the read conversion fails after i persist the modified bean to mongodb. It causes *java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to kam.albert.lab.TestConversion$Person*

So the errornous scenario is this :

1. Create a SimpleObject and populate its map with a Person
2. Store the simpleObject to mongo
3. Find the simpleObject and get the Person instance from the map, which triggers *java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to kam.albert.lab.TestConversion$Person*

So i assume, the read conversion for the Person seems to fail when reading the Person from inside a map, although the write conversion was successful when the first insertion happened. I can see in mongo that the data fields are correct as defined in the write converter.
Also in another experiment, i put the Person not in the map, and all read and write conversion worked fine. It seems to be problematic when doing read-conversion only if we put this instance in a map.
The source is provided below :

```
package kam.albert.lab;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;

@Component
public class TestConversion {

    @Autowired private MongoOperations ops;

    public static class Person {
        private String firstName, lastName;
        public Person(String first, String last) {
            this.firstName = first;
            this.lastName = last;
        }
    }
    public static class PersonWriteConverter implements Converter<Person, DBObject> {
        @Override
        public DBObject convert(Person person) {
            DBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
            dbObject.put("first", person.firstName);
            dbObject.put("last", person.lastName);
            return dbObject;
        }

    }
    public static class PersonReadConverter implements Converter<DBObject, Person> {
        @Override
        public Person convert(DBObject dbo) {
            return new Person((String)dbo.get("first"), (String)dbo.get("last"));
        }
    }
    public static class SimpleObject {
        private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        private Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        public SimpleObject addPerson(String first, String last) {
            this.map.put(String.valueOf(this.map.size()), new Person(first, last));
            return this;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "test-conversion-context.xml"
        );
        TestConversion bean = ctx.getBean(TestConversion.class);
        bean.cleanup();
        String id = bean.testWrite();
        bean.testRead(id);
        bean.testUpdate(id); // this causes the read below to fail
        bean.testRead(id);
    }

    private void cleanup() {
        this.ops.dropCollection("testconv");
    }

    private String testWrite() {
        SimpleObject simpleObject = new SimpleObject();
        simpleObject.addPerson("albert", "kam");
        this.ops.insert(simpleObject, "testconv");
        return simpleObject.id;
    }

    private void testRead(String id) {
        SimpleObject simpleObject = this.ops.findById(id, SimpleObject.class, "testconv");
        System.out.println("read success : " + simpleObject.map);
    }

    private void testUpdate(String id) {
        SimpleObject simpleObject = this.ops.findById(id, SimpleObject.class, "testconv");
        Person person = (Person) simpleObject.map.get("0"); // this causes exception !
        person.firstName = "a new first name";
//      simpleObject.addPerson("new", "person"); // this is fine
        Update update = new Update().set("map", simpleObject.map);
        this.ops.updateFirst(Query.query(Criteria.where("_id").is(id)), update, "testconv");
    }
}
```

And the test-conversion-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang" 
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- default id = mongo, host = localhost, and port = 27017 no nested options 
        for now -->
    <mongo:mongo>
        <mongo:options />
    </mongo:mongo>

    <!-- to translate any exceptions from @Repository annotated classes -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <mongo:db-factory dbname="glasswing" mongo-ref="mongo" />

    <util:constant id="writeConcern" static-field="com.mongodb.WriteConcern.SAFE" />
    <util:constant id="writeResultChecking" static-field="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.WriteResultChecking.EXCEPTION" />

    <bean id="ops" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
        <constructor-arg name="mongoConverter" ref="mappingConverter" />

        <property name="writeConcern" ref="writeConcern" />
        <property name="writeResultChecking" ref="writeResultChecking" />
    </bean>

    <mongo:mapping-converter base-package="kam.albert.domain.converter">
        <mongo:custom-converters>
            <mongo:converter><bean class="kam.albert.lab.TestConversion.PersonWriteConverter" /></mongo:converter>
            <mongo:converter><bean class="kam.albert.lab.TestConversion.PersonReadConverter" /></mongo:converter>
        </mongo:custom-converters>
    </mongo:mapping-converter>

    <context:spring-configured />

    <context:load-time-weaver/>

    <bean id="testConversion" class="kam.albert.lab.TestConversion" />  
 </beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as designed. If you register a custom `Converter` implementation it will have to provide the complete `DBObject`. Our mapping infrastructure will not treat it any further.

This means, if you provide a custom converter you need to equip the `DBObject` created with the type information necessary. Otherwise we will not be able to resolve the type to create (and thus in turn not know about potential custom converters needed to be invoked) in polymorphic scenarios.

I've created a [sample test case](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-mongodb/commit/d3d480e79b1ac948f6aee51279c30f5f0d65180c) showing that the polymorphic scenario works *if* you let the writing converter populate the `DBObject` with type information.

Comment: jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAMONGO-724

Answer (score 0):

Solved with hacks described in http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?139797-SOLVED-custom-write-converter-on-updating-entity-that-contains-a-map&p=450945#post450945